# splitting css into 2 css files using node js and rework

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, css

how to split one css file into two for ex: to generate 2 outputs of following form using node js and reworkcss/css
https://github.com/reworkcss/css

```
main.css
 body{
        color: blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: red;
 }
 h1 , div{
        color: red;
 }

 output1.css
 body{
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: red;
 }
 output2.css
 body{
        color: blue;
 }
 h1 , div{
        color: red;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? Should the code also work for other files, or are you only interested in this particular case?

Comment: @JCOC611 it should work with .css files

Comment: @JCOC611 i just want to split one .css file into two depending on the requirement just like in above case i want to separate color property from main css and create a new css having all tags with color property

Comment: writing `output1.css` would make the original CSS file invalid, no?

Comment: @kumar_harsh not exactly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two ast files, one for `font-size` and `background-color`:

```
{
  "type": "stylesheet",
  "stylesheet": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "type": "rule",
        "selectors": [*],
        "declarations": [
          {
            "type": "declaration",
            "property": "font-size",
            "value": "",
            "position": {
              "start": {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 1
              },
              "end": {
                "line": 99,
                "column": 99
              },
              "source": "input.css"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "declaration",
            "property": "background-color",
            "value": "",
            "position": {
              "start": {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 1
              },
              "end": {
                "line": 99,
                "column": 99
              },
              "source": "input.css"
            }
        ],
        "position": {
          "start": {
            "line": 1,
            "column": 1
          },
          "end": {
            "line": 99,
            "column": 99
          },
          "source": "input.css"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and another for the  rest:

```
{
  "type": "stylesheet",
  "stylesheet": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "type": "rule",
        "selectors": [*],
        "declarations": [
          {
            "type": "declaration",
            "property": "color",
            "value": "",
            "position": {
              "start": {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 1
              },
              "end": {
                "line": 99,
                "column": 99
              },
              "source": "input.css"
            }
          }
        ],
        "position": {
          "start": {
            "line": 1,
            "column": 1
          },
          "end": {
            "line": 99,
            "column": 99
          },
          "source": "input.css"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**References**

- [reworkcss test cases: selectors - ast.json](https://github.com/reworkcss/css/blob/master/test/cases/selectors/ast.json)
- [Custom CSS preprocessing – Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/custom-css-preprocessing/)